# How to Convert a Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, databricks

In databricks, I created a spark dataframe, and need to convert it to a pandas dataframe,

```
 sdf = spark.sql('select * from my_tbl')
 pdf = sdf.toPandas()
```

but got error:

```
ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[us, tz=America/New_York] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp: 253402214400000000
File <command-1629564213930490>, line 1
----> 1 pdf=sdf.toPandas()
```

I am just wondering how to fix this, or is there anyway to generate a panda dataframe by directly invoking SQL in databricks?

Comment: can you post a sample of your input dataframe?

Comment: do not know how to edit the question, but just added sample dataframe as a answer below. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering indicates an issue with the timestamp conversion. You can try:

```
df = sdf.toPandas(timestampFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

Comment: still got error: --- TypeError: DataFrame.toPandas() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestampFormat' ----       import datetime applied, not sure if something else needed

Comment: not sure what is the dtype of the timestamp column you have, but you can try casting it first to string:

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sdf = sdf.withColumn('Trans_dtt', F.col('Trans_dtt').cast("string"))
df = sdf.toPandas()